# How to use metafield value in Shopify APP

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I have created metafield using API. Currently accessing those Metafield in shopify cart.liquid like given below -

```
{{shop.metafields.AnnexCloud.access_token}}
```

Getting correct value using above syntax.
But when I try to access Metafield through above syntax in APP files facing issue.

I am creating new shopify public APP using python. In that want access metafield using

```
{{shop.metafields.AnnexCloud.access_token}}
```

So, please help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure what you mean about accessing that metafield through your app - there are lots of places where you might be trying to use that value, so I'll try to cover a few of the bases here.

### If you're trying to access the metafield in your Python code

Your app is not running on Shopify's servers and doesn't have any native concept of Liquid code. However, since your app is running on your servers with access to whatever database you've used to store the data you need, you shouldn't need to access this metafield - you should have all the information you need already saved.

That said, if your app's requirements have put you in a position where you need to read that live from the store, you can use your app's credentials to access `[the-store-domain.myshopify.com]/admin/metafields.json` to get metafield information into your app.  You can refine your request as well - for example, `[the-store-domain.myshopify.com]/admin/metafields.json?namespace=atuls-app` would only return metafields where the `namespace` was `atuls-app`.

### If you're trying to access the metafield in your app's front-end code

You unfortunately won't be able to put the liquid drop into any file inside of the store's `/assets` folder (if you're writing any files there), nor will you be able to put any Liquid inside of any assets your app loads through the `content_for_header`.

For the latter case, though, the scripts loaded through `content_for_header` would be coming from your server, so you could use any of the methods listed above to get that value injected into the script file through your server's code/logic.

For the former case, where you are adding a file to the `/assets` folder of a Shopify theme, you would only have access to a very limited number of Liquid variables (and unfortunately `shop` isn't one of them).  To get around this, you would need your app's install to add a `script` tag to the `layouts/theme.liquid` file to save a global variable with the contents of your metafield.  Any other scripts would then be able to access that global variable. (Note: this method comes with all the normal caveats/considerations about using global variables for things)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @Dave B actually I am going to create different Apps for different module. But all Apps need some common values. So, I created one configuration App for saving common values in metafields rather than saving in each App. Let consider one of metafield is for Site_ID. Now I need to access this Site_ID from my configuration App to another App's front-end code

Comment: Hmmm...  Is there anything blocking you from having a centralized database table on your servers that all of your apps can talk to for those common values?  My personal preference would be to have have some kind of Central Command service running that all my apps could talk to for those common values, but I understand that kind of structure might not be applicable for every situation.